# Bluehost Wordpress Site hacked multiple times FTP MMprobe php file

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

Anyone have experience and advice to locate the source and stop an ftp hack on my client's Wordpress site hosted on BlueHost? The hackers were able to do the following:

1. Create multiple ftp accounts with usernames like `ss-ee4f8275917dfe28` etc. pointing to folders `/tmp/simplescripts/` and `/public_html/`
2. Upload php files with names like `MMprobe-N5ayJ.php` into the `public_html` folder

Comment: We cannot possibly know the source of an attack by looking at what they did afterwards.

Comment: Contact a professional to aid you.

Comment: I just noticed the same FTP accounts that were created and pointing to the "simplescripts" folder. The other FTP accounts point to my root folder. I think this attack happened long ago but the extra FTP accounts went unnoticed.

Comment: apparently these accounts are created by one-click-installs within the cpanel... so the "hacker" would be bluehost's hosting platform itself.
I just was looking at the same issue, and saw that commentes. makes a kind of sense, though is not at all a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best scenario would be to take the last backup of the website and just re-create it fresh on a new server. You should contact their support for help. There could possibly be rootkits and other hidden stuff inside your application files, which could take a lot of time to weed out.

To prevent FTP attacks

- use latest FTP service version
- use strong username, password
- setup fail2ban on FTP to prevent brute-force attacks